# setSharing method on App Script not working for G Suite users?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a document and set its access permissions. 
The code below works on my normal Gmail account.

However, when I run it on my unique GSuite address, it returns this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function setSharing in object Document. (line
>   6, file "Code")

Here is the code:

```
    function createAndSendDocument() {

  //Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello, world!'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello World');

  //Set user permissions to view and edit.
  doc.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);

  //Access the body of the document, then add a Paragraph.
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This is a test document for people to see and try and lorem ipsum.');

  //Get the URL of the doc
  var url = doc.getUrl();

  //Get email address of the active user - aka you.
  var email = 'example@domain.com';

  //Get the name of doc to use as an email subject line
  var subject = doc.getName();

  //Add a new strong to the url variable to use as an email body.
  var body = 'Link to your document: ' + url;

  //Send yourself an email with a link to the document.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body); 

}
```

How can I work around this or use the setSharing method correctly? Am I using the wrong method or am I missing other steps as

Comment: Are you talking about the email here var email = 'example@domain.com'; ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem from a non GSuite account and solved it by using the Drive api instead of the Document one.

e.g.

```
var drivedoc = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
drivedoc.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

worked but it did not when I used `DocumentApp.getFileById`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem myself that might help you. I used the DocumentApp api to create a document. Then I used the DriveApp api to set the sharing. Notice the the URLs you get from the same document are different. If you email the URL you get for the document from the DocumentApp with someone outside your G Suite organization, they will have to sign in to open the document even though the sharing is set to "Anyone with the link. No sign-in required." But if you email the URL that you get from DriveApp to the person outside your G Suite organization, they will be able to open the link easily, with no sign-in required. So I think your code might work better if you used DriveApp to set the sharing of the document you create. Then make sure that you email the URL you get from the DriveApp api instead of the URL you get from the DocumentApp api.

```
function myFunction() {
var doc = DocumentApp.create("Test Document");
Logger.log("This is the URL that I get with DocumentApp: " + doc.getUrl());

var documentFileID = doc.getId();
var myFileDriveApp = DriveApp.getFileById(documentFileID);
Logger.log("This is the drive app URL: " + myFileDriveApp.getUrl());

//Set the sharing on the file using DriveApp
myFileDriveApp.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

}